# Determine feature importance of nested regression model

Tags: regression, feature-selection, weights, weighted-regression, nested-models

For remote sensing purposes, I'm trying to combine data from two different satellites. To do so, one of the two has a much higher weight than the other, but this is area specific. My goal is to use a regression model which will predict the optimal weight distribution for a specific area, depending on a number of features (such as topography, precipitation, landcover, etc.).
My questions are:

1. can this be done using a regression model? And if so, which one do you think is best for this purpose?
2. What would be the best way to obtain the feature importance? With Pearson's correlation or mutual information statistics (or something else)?

So I guess that what I'm trying is to determine the feature importance for a nested regression model.

Comment: Do you have a "ground truth" (=what you want the weighted average - or whatever the weight is exactly used as - to look like)? Is there some understanding of the physics that would suggest it could be possible to directly mathematically describe the physical system or at least suggest strong determinants (=features to use in a model) of what satellite should get more weight (instead of using a model that might fail to make use of any of our understanding of how the physics of the situation work)?

Comment: Of a few areas, I do have a ground truth from direct measurements, but I'm afraid this is too little to use as validation data. I do also have access to higher resolution images which do not show the ground truth, but in which a similar pattern is visible. So far I haven't come across any physics describing such a model, I think because there are so many variables involved.

Comment: Without ground truth (or some imperfect surrogate) labels it is hard to see how one would use regression to figure out how to combine images. How do you as a human judge what "looks better"?